# Newsletter stuck in sending

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, magento1.9.2.4

When i create newsletter and apply for queue, then it stuck in sending. You can find more information in screenshot attached bellow.

**Magento 1.9.2.4**

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Your `smtp` works fine ? the Emails orders, account , works without problem ?

Comment: Yes, Email Orders and All working fine, Only This newsletter not working.